Symfony logging users out after sending a StreamedResponse
I have a Symfony 6.3 application that enables users to produce a report.
They can click a button to download the report, which is working fine, but then if they navigate to another page (or refresh the current page) the user is forced to login again.
Strangely enough, this only happens on the production server.
Here is the relevant code returned by the controller:
$writer = new XlsxWriter($this->spreadsheet);

        $response = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($writer) {
            var_dump("Hello");
            //$writer->save('php://output');
        });


        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', "attachment;filename=\"Report.xlsx\"");
       $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');

        return $response;

The report is a spreadsheet, but the same thing happens if the file contains a simple string, as above.

Just as a side note: keep in mind that Symfony 6.3 is out of support since some months. Maybe you're facing a bug that was resolved in a later version?

Thanks @NicoHaase, it's on my to do list to update it. However, the fact I don't experience this behaviour when it runs locally in Docker leads me to believe it isn't a bug.

What's the difference between the two systems? Did you try to run your application within your Docker setup with APP_ENV=prod to reproduce the problem?

I have indeed, as well as temporarily setting  APP_ENV=dev on the production server. The former doesn't reproduce the problem, and the latter doesn't stop it. I can't think of any obvious differences between the systems, but then I don't know where to begin looking. Any pointers?

It turns out this had nothing to do with the StreamedResponse per se.
Somewhere in the code that produced the report was a line that triggered a PHP Warning. This, in turn, generated a 'headers already sent' exception. As a consequence, I believe this invalidated the session.
Improving the code so no warnings are produced has resolved the issue above.
What's probably more helpful to note is the warning only came to light when setting APP_ENV=dev on the production server.
I guess the difference between the server and the docker is the level of error reporting PHP is set to.
